# Disprove that if $n$ is an odd positive integer greater than $1$ then $2^n-1$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Disprove that if $n$ is an odd positive integer greater than $1$ then $2^n-1$ is prime.

So my approach to this is as follows but I have no idea where to go from here or whether this is the right approach.

Let $n=2x+1$ where $x\in\Bbb Z^+$

Then  $2^n+1=2^{2x+1}-1$

$=6(2^n)-1$

Comment: All you need is a single counterexample, and there is a fairly small one.

Comment: is there not a way this can be proved by deduction then?

Comment: You are trying to disprove something.  In truth, there are primes of this form and there are composites of this form.  To disprove this claim you just need to find a single composite example.

Comment: If you want a harder problem, you can try to prove that there are infinitely many composites of this form.

Comment: Oh okay, the question is worth 4 marks and i thought a simple counter example way to simple

Comment: Nope.  All it takes is one counterexample to disprove a theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

- **If $n$ is composite, then $2^n-1$ is composite**. The prove is not hard to follow up. *since $n$ is composite, $n = km$. This implies that $2^{km}-1 = (2^k-1)(1+2^k+2^{2k}+2^{3k}...+2^{km-1})$.*
- **If $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime**. The prove can be deduced from the previous part by "counter-positiv*ing*" this statement. "NOTE THAT THE CONVERSE IS NOT TRUE".

A quick counter example to disprove, take $n$ to be $9$, then $ 2^9-1 = 511 = 7*73$ which is divisible by $2^3 - 1 = 7$ and $1+2^3+2^6 = 73$.

Comment: There is a much smaller counterexample. Since you know $n$ must be composite, what's the first thing to try?

Comment: @EthanBolker The first odd $n$ to be a counterexample seems to be $9$. Is there a smaller number?

Comment: Oops missed the "odd". Sorry.

Comment: @EthanBolker I guessed so :).

Answer (score 0):

Take $$2^{11}-1=23\cdot 89$$ and this number is not prime

Comment: is n=9 not a simpler example?

Comment: Here is also the exponent prime!